# how to solve api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll without windows update?

Tags: php, apache, server

[image]
Actually, when I update my windows, my computer becomes too **slow**. So now when I'm trying to run **Apache** it gets error "**api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll**". I googled a lot about this issue but what I found is to update windows, where this problem relates to the update version **KB2999226**.
So I want to install only KB2999226, I'm looking for this update in Windows Update, but I can't found it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issues recently.. I just fixed mine now... The solution is to install Microsoft visual c++ 2015... 
get it here >>
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840

if you get and error message that says "0X80070424 does not exist as an install service" then you would have to reinstall the windows OS...
remember to backup important files before doing so.

I also had to do all this before I got mine to work.

I hope this answer is not coming too late.